# Problem with Python tkinter (image does not appear as button)

Tags: python, function, tkinter

**First:** In code below i want to use instead of default rectangle button, images prepared by myslef.

This generates some problems (mayby with reference)? This button does not appear as image, also i am not able to use function (name: **load_frame_insert()**) after click.

**Second: I wonder to have 2 bbtns:**

1. Normal: assets/insert_data.png
2. OnClick: assets/insert_data2.png

**Could you help me?**

PS. Doesn't work after moving from up-down code to code with functions

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk


# DB connector
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                      'SERVER=onyx1905;'
                      'DATABASE=DW_15;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes')

# variables
name = os.getlogin()
cursor = conn.cursor()
running = True
bg_color_1 = "#205E61"
bg_button = "#1B4E51"
bg_button_ac = "#FFD966"
global img_button_1

def image_button_1(size):
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/insert_data.png")
    img = img.subsample(size, size)
    return img
    #button img: insert_data
    #button img: insert_data_on_click

def clear_widgets(frame):
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()


def load_main_frame():

    clear_widgets(frame_insert)
    frame_main.tkraise()
    frame_main.pack_propagate(False)

    # widget frame_main logo
    logo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="assets/xrdl_logo.png")
    logo_widget = tk.Label(frame_main, image=logo_image, bg=bg_color_1)
    logo_widget.image = logo_image
    logo_widget.pack()

    # label on 1st frame
    tk.Label(
        frame_main,
        text=(f"          Hi {name}, please choose an action        "),
        bg=bg_button,
        fg="white",
        font=("TkMenuFont", 12)
        ).pack(pady=10)

    # btn code on 1st frame
    tk.Button(
        frame_main,
        image=image_button_1(1),
        bd=0,
        relief="groove",
        compound=tk.CENTER,
        bg=bg_color_1,
        fg="yellow",
        activeforeground="pink",
        activebackground=bg_color_1,
        font=("TkMenuFont", 12),
        cursor="hand2",
        text="",
        command=lambda: load_frame_insert()
        ).pack(pady=5)


def load_frame_insert():
    print("Hi XYZ")

# ini for app
main_app = tk.Tk()
main_app.title("SRD Loader")
main_app.eval("tk::PlaceWindow . center")

x = main_app.winfo_screenwidth() // 3
y = int(main_app.winfo_screenheight() * 0.1)
main_app.geometry('500x600+' + str(x) + '+' + str(y))

# frame look
frame_main = tk.Frame(main_app, width=500, height=600, bg=bg_color_1)
frame_insert = tk.Frame(main_app, width=500, height=600, bg=bg_color_1)

for frame in (frame_main, frame_insert):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

load_main_frame()
main_app.mainloop()


conn.close()
```

other related topics but doesnt work
youtube tutorials

Comment: You have the `os` module imported and you note this is likely a reference error with your images nit being found, and I tend to agree without seeing your project structure. Why not just try `os.getcwd()` to gather the current working directory to ensure you are grabbing the file correctly?

Comment: `image=image_button_1()` doesn't save the reference of the image, so the image will be garbage collected.

Comment: @ViaTech - about <os> i use this lib for other reason (i must take login from AD)

Comment: @acw1668 could you help me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For the statement `command=image_button_1(1)`, the image returned by `image_button_1(1)` will be garbage collected because there is no variable referencing it.  That is why you get a button without image.

You need to save the reference of the image, for example using an attribute of the button as below:

```py
    image = image_button_1(1)
    btn = tk.Button(
        frame_main,
        image=image,
        bd=0,
        relief="groove",
        compound=tk.CENTER,
        bg=bg_color_1,
        fg="yellow",
        activeforeground="pink",
        activebackground=bg_color_1,
        font=("TkMenuFont", 12),
        cursor="hand2",
        text="",
        command=lambda: load_frame_insert()
        )
    btn.pack(pady=5)
    btn.image = image  # save the reference of the image
```

Answer (score 0):

- I removed three libraries.
- I removed `image_button_1` function
- Added image = tk.PhotoImage(file="p1.png")
- Added variable for `Button`
- Change 5 to 25 `.pack(pady=25)`
- Removed  `lambda` and brace bracket `command=load_frame_insert`

Snippet:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
 
running = True
bg_color_1 = "#205E61"
bg_button = "#1B4E51"
bg_button_ac = "#FFD966"
  
def clear_widgets(frame):
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()


def load_main_frame():

    clear_widgets(frame_insert)
    frame_main.tkraise()
    frame_main.pack_propagate(False)

    # widget frame_main logo
    logo_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="p2.png")
    logo_widget = tk.Label(frame_main, image=logo_image, bg=bg_color_1)
    logo_widget.image = logo_image
    logo_widget.pack()

    # label on 1st frame
    tk.Label(
        frame_main,
        text=(f"Hi please choose an action"),
        bg=bg_button,
        fg="white",
        font=("TkMenuFont", 12)
        ).pack(pady=10)


    image = tk.PhotoImage(file="p1.png")
    # btn code on 1st frame
    btn= tk.Button(
        frame_main,
        image=image,
        bd=0,
        relief="groove",
        compound=tk.CENTER,
        bg=bg_color_1,
        fg="yellow",
        activeforeground="pink",
        activebackground=bg_color_1,
        font=("TkMenuFont", 12),
        cursor="hand2",
        text="",
        command=load_frame_insert 
        )
    btn.pack(pady=25)
    btn.image = image

def load_frame_insert():
    print("Hi XYZ")

# ini for app
main_app = tk.Tk()
main_app.title("SRD Loader")
main_app.eval("tk::PlaceWindow . center")

x = main_app.winfo_screenwidth() // 3
y = int(main_app.winfo_screenheight() * 0.1)
main_app.geometry('500x600+' + str(x) + '+' + str(y))

# frame look
frame_main = tk.Frame(main_app, width=500, height=600, bg=bg_color_1)
frame_insert = tk.Frame(main_app, width=500, height=600, bg=bg_color_1)

for frame in (frame_main, frame_insert):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

load_main_frame()

main_app.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The output : Hi XYZ

Comment: Btw, I don't used pandas and pyodbc. I leave that to you to modified.